# getting data from nutch in plain text format

Tags: html, hadoop, web-crawler, bigdata, nutch

I am using apache nutch to crawl websites. When I am using `readseg` command to read content in a segment, I am getting in the format like below:

[image]

Is there any way to get web data in plain text format?
[when I am using readseg command on parse text I am getting in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN6AA.png)

Comment: Looks like text to me. What were you expecting to get back?

Comment: actually, I am extraction job description data from job portal sites. I just want to extract the job name and its description.but when I am crawling, I am getting in the format mentioned in the question. is there a way to extract data in plain text like my requirement?

Comment: For the next time include the command that you're executing in the question otherwise is very difficult to know what you've tried, or which flags have you tried.

Comment: thank you for the help. I used readseg command on content, parse, parse text, parse data. in everywhere I am getting the metadata only. for example if i want to read parse text, I am using the command like bin/nutch readseg -dump crawler/stat1/segments/20180509083305 urlcontent -nofetch -nocontent -noparse -noparsedata -nogenerate

Answer (score 0):

The `readseg` command dumps (by default) the *raw* content fetched from the URLs. This is the entire HTML content transfered. If you want to get the textual content, you need to wait until after the content is parsed. This means that you need to execute an entire crawl cycle (or the `./bin/nutch parse` command).

Check the different options on the `readseg` command (https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_readseg), if you're already executing the parse step, you probably only care for the parsed content, so you could avoid printing everything else.

Comment: even though I am using the readseg command mentioned above on every segment directory, I am only getting metadata but not any text data from that URL.

Comment: If you specify the `-noparse` flag, you're specifying that you don't want the parsed data i.e the text.

Comment: hey, can you see the image in my question. that is the text what I am getting when I am using readseg on parse text. i am getting all the text in that webpage except the description. can you please help me?

Comment: hey, I did all the processes inject, generate, fetching, parsing, updatedb, invertinglinks. will you please just tell me the command directly to see my crawl data in text format like which to keep and which to not keep after readseg ie., -nocontent -nofetch etc....